# Is it okay to strip UF cable at the point of entry to outside conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

So I've installed a new single-pole 30 amp outdoor waterproof receptacle box and outlet on my house.

Is it ok to run 10/2 UF-B to a receptacle? And is it okay to strip the sheathing where it enters the conduit? (The conduit is outside the home going to a hole in the wall where the wire will enter).

With all the information on the internet- I am getting mixed answers in my search results.

Comment: What type of box are you using for the receptacle, and is there a reason you can't make the run entirely on the inside of the house?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel while your suggestion of making the run entirely within the house is excellent, running _through_ a finished wall takes a lot more work (especially for Joe-Average DIYer) than attaching some conduit to the outside of said wall, especially if there's no convenient attic/basement/crawl space.

Comment: For code related questions we need to know where you live.

Answer (score 4):

If you are intending to strip the outer sheath from the UF-B cable to  make it easier to pull the three contained individual wires through the conduit, the answer is **NO**. The individual wires inside the cable do not have the proper markings to be run without their sheath. Additionally it is the outer sheath itself that is critical to the cable's overall weather-proof rating. Without that outer sheath, it is no longer "UF-B" rated cable, it's just some wires of unknown rating. Any exterior conduit is *assumed* to be wet, and any wire/cable run through it *must* be marked as suitable for wet locations.

Since you have conduit, it would be appropriate to use 3 THHN/THWN rated individual wires (Black, White, Green would be appropriate colors) to pull through the conduit, but you must continue the conduit inside the house to a junction box where you can switch to NM-B to exit the box/conduit. I was surprised to find that 3 individual spools of THHN/THWN were priced slightly cheaper in comparison to a /2 cable of the same AWG for a project I did last summer and it made life much easier.

Note: If you need code references, there are tons of answers here where you will find them and/or a licensed electrician will be along shortly would would, I'm sure, be happy to provide them once again.